# How can I add degree signs to the numbers on the x axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to add degree signs to the numbers on the x axis, as shown in this picture. How can I do this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone} 
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents*}{Fre.dat}
       0.0000000e+00   9.7322390e+00   1.3985949e+01   1.5525350e+01
       2.5000000e+00   9.7404206e+00   1.4001132e+01   1.5546305e+01
       5.0000000e+00   9.7651029e+00   1.4046619e+01   1.5609681e+01
       7.5000000e+00   9.8067018e+00   1.4122249e+01   1.5717003e+01
       1.0000000e+01   9.8659247e+00   1.4227833e+01   1.5870771e+01
       1.2500000e+01   9.9437917e+00   1.4363269e+01   1.6074399e+01
       1.5000000e+01   1.0041667e+01   1.4528713e+01   1.6332129e+01
       1.7500000e+01   1.0161304e+01   1.4724777e+01   1.6648943e+01
       2.0000000e+01   1.0304897e+01   1.4952727e+01   1.7030511e+01
       2.2500000e+01   1.0475157e+01   1.5214662e+01   1.7483207e+01
       2.5000000e+01   1.0675401e+01   1.5513636e+01   1.8014219e+01
       2.7500000e+01   1.0909671e+01   1.5853762e+01   1.8631749e+01
       3.0000000e+01   1.1182876e+01   1.6240296e+01   1.9345313e+01
       3.2500000e+01   1.1500982e+01   1.6679755e+01   2.0166108e+01
       3.5000000e+01   1.1871246e+01   1.7180085e+01   2.1107451e+01
       3.7500000e+01   1.2302522e+01   1.7750913e+01   2.2185310e+01
       4.0000000e+01   1.2805653e+01   1.8403905e+01   2.3418947e+01
       4.2500000e+01   1.3393986e+01   1.9153253e+01   2.4831704e+01
       4.5000000e+01   1.4084049e+01   2.0016348e+01   2.6045676e+01
       4.7500000e+01   1.4896463e+01   2.1014686e+01   2.7132868e+01
       5.0000000e+01   1.5857171e+01   2.2175104e+01   2.8395420e+01
       5.2500000e+01   1.6999148e+01   2.3531505e+01   2.9867785e+01
       5.5000000e+01   1.8364789e+01   2.5127277e+01   3.1594083e+01
       5.7500000e+01   2.0009352e+01   2.7018776e+01   3.3631631e+01
       6.0000000e+01   2.2006006e+01   2.9280464e+01   3.6056144e+01 
    \end{filecontents*}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot file [x index=0,y index=1] {Fre.dat};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Looking at your question "history", you should really start accepting answers if they have helped you. It's s way of saying "thank you" in this community, and also show that your problem was solved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `xticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$}` to the options for the `axis`.

Here `\tick` is a macro that holds the number for the current tick, while `\pgfmathprintnumber` pretty-prints that number (so you don't get e.g. 20.00000000001).

Perhaps useful to note that `xticklabel` used here is not the same as `xticklabels`. The latter lets you specify a comma separated list of custom ticklabels, while `xticklabel={..}` lets you specify a "format", as shown above, where the numeric value of the tick can be used.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{Fre.dat}
   0.0000000e+00   9.7322390e+00   1.3985949e+01   1.5525350e+01
   2.5000000e+00   9.7404206e+00   1.4001132e+01   1.5546305e+01
   5.0000000e+00   9.7651029e+00   1.4046619e+01   1.5609681e+01
   7.5000000e+00   9.8067018e+00   1.4122249e+01   1.5717003e+01
   1.0000000e+01   9.8659247e+00   1.4227833e+01   1.5870771e+01
   1.2500000e+01   9.9437917e+00   1.4363269e+01   1.6074399e+01
   1.5000000e+01   1.0041667e+01   1.4528713e+01   1.6332129e+01
   1.7500000e+01   1.0161304e+01   1.4724777e+01   1.6648943e+01
   2.0000000e+01   1.0304897e+01   1.4952727e+01   1.7030511e+01
   2.2500000e+01   1.0475157e+01   1.5214662e+01   1.7483207e+01
   2.5000000e+01   1.0675401e+01   1.5513636e+01   1.8014219e+01
   2.7500000e+01   1.0909671e+01   1.5853762e+01   1.8631749e+01
   3.0000000e+01   1.1182876e+01   1.6240296e+01   1.9345313e+01
   3.2500000e+01   1.1500982e+01   1.6679755e+01   2.0166108e+01
   3.5000000e+01   1.1871246e+01   1.7180085e+01   2.1107451e+01
   3.7500000e+01   1.2302522e+01   1.7750913e+01   2.2185310e+01
   4.0000000e+01   1.2805653e+01   1.8403905e+01   2.3418947e+01
   4.2500000e+01   1.3393986e+01   1.9153253e+01   2.4831704e+01
   4.5000000e+01   1.4084049e+01   2.0016348e+01   2.6045676e+01
   4.7500000e+01   1.4896463e+01   2.1014686e+01   2.7132868e+01
   5.0000000e+01   1.5857171e+01   2.2175104e+01   2.8395420e+01
   5.2500000e+01   1.6999148e+01   2.3531505e+01   2.9867785e+01
   5.5000000e+01   1.8364789e+01   2.5127277e+01   3.1594083e+01
   5.7500000e+01   2.0009352e+01   2.7018776e+01   3.3631631e+01
   6.0000000e+01   2.2006006e+01   2.9280464e+01   3.6056144e+01 
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$^\circ$}]
  \addplot file [x index=0,y index=1] {Fre.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```